# Passport Package returning "Unauthenticated" Error

Tags: laravel, api, token, laravel-passport

I am using Passport Package for the API requests. It was working fine with my old server and the request was authenticated but since I have moved my application to a newer server I am receiving Invalid Token Error. Been searching on the google from last 2 days but didn't find any solution.

The API successfully returning me the token but when I am using that token to authenticate the user it gives me "Unauthenticated" error and redirects me to Home.

Everything is working fine on my old server. Not sure what to change to get this working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the same `config/auth.php` between both servers, including the `.env` entries?

Comment: yes both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check webServer probably it does not forward auth headers to php backend

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

Comment: should I add this to my .htaccess hile?

Comment: this is nginx rules apache config depend on mpd_php / cgi_module connection

Comment: I added these 2 lines in my .htaccess file, after adding these the api got working but my css and images of the website disappear.
Here is my code of .htacess file

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Comment: Please let me know where should I add these lines which you provided because I can't add them in htaccess file.

Comment: google`it "apache bearer token" or something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new client credentials

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

Or regenerate the keys

```
php artisan passport:keys --force
```